# python split function does not work as expected

Tags: python, split

I am having a hard time to formulate what my problem is... It concerns this piece of code here:

```
def txt_to_dict_ad():

    my_dict = {}    

    with open('database.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            temp = list(line.strip().split('-'))
            my_dict[temp[1].strip('\n')] = temp[0]

    return my_dict
```

When I run it and for example want to print the output of this function, I am getting an "index out of range" error for the line containing temp[1] and temp[0]. Why is that? And how can I avoid it?

The txt file contains Arabic and German vocabulary,
Example data: Auto - سيارة

Comment: Example data might help. Assuming you have strings of data with underscore separators, your indexes shouldn't cause problems. Fyi you don't need the list() call. Split method returns a list.

Comment: Unless you have an empty line at the end of your file...

Comment: I just added an example line to my posting. I know that .split() returns a list but there was some kind of problem which I could fix by turning it into a list explicitly... Although  dont know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a line in `database.txt` does not contain a `-`, then the variable `temp` contains a list with one element only and `temp[1]` of the next line tries to access the non-existent second element and will therefore throw the error.

You can avoid the error by ignoring lines without `-`, for example.

```
if '-' in line:
    temp = list(line.strip().split('-'))
    my_dict[temp[1].strip('\n')] = temp[0]
```

If you want to identify the lines without hyhen:

```
with open('database.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
        if '-' in line:
            temp = list(line.strip().split('-'))
            my_dict[temp[1].strip('\n')] = temp[0]
        else:
            print('Line {} misses the underscore.'.format(i))
```

Comment: That's it, now it works... Which is really weird because there is actually no line without a '_' in my file. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: @hmw1001 Maybe, an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: @hmw1001 also in your question you are splitting by '-' not '_'

Comment: @MoeA Thanks. Question [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44609636/2) had used the underscore. I have now updated the question to match question [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44609636/2) that uses the hyphen as separating symbol.